# Ununderstandable Rails 3.0 log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, logging, ruby-on-rails-3

since i migrated to rails 3.0, logs are now filled with queries like this:

```
 SQL (8.5ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"checkins"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
  SQL (0.7ms)   SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM pg_tables
 WHERE tablename = 'checkins'
```

it look like some Postgresql system query, but the log is really unreadable now, i have to scroll through hundred of lines like this to find what i want. is there a reason? is there a way to get the same logging as rails 2? I can't manage to find anything about it on google.
Thank you!

Comment: You have an Models Checkin ? or a table checkins ?

Comment: Both, but that's just an example, i got this kind of message with all  tables used in a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at http://github.com/dolzenko/silent-postgres
That plugin strips those queries out. Those log noise occurs because of the high postgresql log level.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, but i didn't thank it can be a plugin. I was searching for rails logger obscure options. Thanks a lot!